# inconsistent activation settings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker, fire-and-forget

I have a service  that uses the infamous fire and forget pattern (don't judge me, I didn't create it) that was working fine on SQL Server 2005. I recently upgraded to 2012 and now ssbdiagnose is complaining about inconsistent activation settings:

```
The activation settings for queue dbo.ScanSendQueue are inconsistent: Activation is configured but disabled
The activation settings for queue dbo.ScanSendQueue are inconsistent: Activation is configured with 0 max_queue_readers
The activation settings for queue dbo.ScanSendQueue are inconsistent: Activation is configured but no procedure is specified
```

I tried to figure out how to solve this but couldn't figure it out short of adding a stored procedure to the "Send" queue, but I can't see why that's necessary.

The basic setup is:

1. Insert to "Scan in" table
2. Trigger calls "Send" service like so:

   `BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @SBDialog
   FROM SERVICE ScanSendService
   TO SERVICE 'ScanReceiveService', 'CURRENT DATABASE'
   ON CONTRACT ScanContract 
   WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF`
3. "Receive" service calls a stored procedure which then does irrelevant stuff. Queue detail below:

   `ALTER QUEUE [dbo].[ScanReceiveQueue] WITH STATUS = ON , RETENTION = OFF , ACTIVATION (  STATUS = ON , PROCEDURE_NAME = [dbo].[usp_Process_ScanReceiveQueue] , MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1 , EXECUTE AS OWNER  ), POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING (STATUS = OFF)`

Messages make it into "Send" queue just fine, but not the "Receive" queue. Why is ssbdiagnose complaining about this, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: More info, since no one seems to have any ideas :(

I took a look at `Microsoft.SqlServer.ServiceBroker.Diagnostics.dll` and it seems that all these checks are being run on every queue regardless of whether "Activation is configured" or not, but I don't even know how to not configure activation....

Source if anyone is interested: https://gist.github.com/Mansfield7/5766457#file-gistfile1-cs-L12

EDIT 2: I turned on activation for that queue and specified a stored procedure that did nothing. The ssbdiagnose errors went away, but the queue is still broken (receive queue still empty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding activation properly for that queue, the ssbdiagnose errors went away, but the services still weren't working.

I attached the SQL Server profiler and saw that the database was not in trusted mode, so I ran the following command, and it started working.

`ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;`

I'd still be curious to know more about the ssbdiagnose warnings about activation, but for now my problem is solved.